# How does damage dealt increase as you level up

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, character-advancement, character-levels

I've recently taken over as GM in my group.  We are all new to RPGs except for our original GM, so they decided to run an adventure path so it would be easier to change GMs if they had to stop playing.  Along this path, we had one CR 4 encounter that took us an hour, almost killed our bloodrager and knocked our brawler unconscious. When we leveled up, our GM told us to increase the damage we did by "one level," so my 1d6 became 2d6 and my friend's 2d6 became 4d6.  I saw no problem with this as a player, but I was looking over the adventure path and later encounters that also have a CR of 4 could be ended in one turn by our bloodrager. This would make encounters really boring, and my goal is to avoid boredom.

My question is: As you level up, how does the damage you do increase? Does it go up like my GM said so that at level 3 my rapier does 3d6 and the bloodrager's earth breaker does 6d6, or does it go up by some other method?

I have read the PHB and I don't think that what the GM was saying is correct, but being a first-time player I wasn't sure if had just missed something, so I figured I should ask elsewhere.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your damage does **not** increase by level. *(1)*

*(1) At least not directly. You get more feats, hit more often, have higher base stats, may aquire magic items and get stronger spells. But the raw damage does not increase. If a weapon does 1d6 damage, it does so, regardless of your level. Exceptions will be noted in the damage text.*

Comment: You should add that sneak attack and caster levels do kindof work this way, but their not weapons

Comment: @Fering My comment was deleted, so I will repeat it: "Exceptions will be noted in the damage text." If the text says *1d6 per Level* then it should be obvious that it's per level. But there's no hidden level modifier, not for weapons and not for spells.

Answer (score 5):

Weapon damage dice never increase with level; they can increase with greater character size and occasionally with class features (mostly Monk and company) or feats, but never directly with level.