# How do I calculate weapon damage as I level up?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, damage, character-advancement

I updated my weapons' damage rolls with the help of a friend when I reached level 13, but now I'm level 16, and I don't know how to do it myself.

My weapons are a huge size Chakram (ranged), a Web Knife (melee) and a Whip Dagger (ranged(with the Web Knife attached.)) At level 13 they were:

- 2d6+14 for my Chakram.
- 1d6+6 for the Web Knife.
- 1d8+6 for the Whip Dagger.

My current attack bonuses are +19/+14/+9 for melee and +18/+13/+8 for ranged. My Strength is 24. I have the Brutal Throw and Boomerang Throw feats.

Comment: What's your Strength? Are you using any feats or abilities that allow adding Dexterity or Wisdom to damage? Do you have Power Attack?

Comment: My strength is 24, and I'm not exactly sure, I don't think I do. I have the Brutal Throw and Boomerang Throw feats.

Comment: Did anything else change between levels 13 and 16 for your character? strength, feats? Because your damage does not scale with level, it might scale with things you got through these levels though.

Comment: c.f. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64521/how-does-damage-dealt-increase-as-you-level-up?rq=1 , which is for pathfinder but the answer is essentially the same.

Comment: Reopened because questions about different games can't be duplicates of each other.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you source the web knife and the feat Boomerang Throw?

Answer (score 6):

Damage is calculated as follows: *Damage Die + Strength Modifier + Equipment Modifiers + Feats and Class Features*

**Damage Die**: This is determined by the type and size of weapon. A longsword deals 1d8 damage. There is a [table](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#tableWeapons) on the SRD (and in the Player's Handbook) that lists each weapon's base damage. There is another table slightly farther up that page which shows how to modify that weapon's damage for each size.

In your case, Chakram, Whip Knife, and Web Dagger are all non-SRD weapons, so that table won't help you. Your damage dice don't change as you level up, however, so they remain 2d6, 1d6, and 1d8.

**Strength Modifier**: This is determined by your strength score, and can be calculated by (STR-10)/2, round down. For two-handed weapons, multiply the result by 1.5 (and round down again). For off-hand weapons, multiply the result by 0.5 (and round down).

**Equipment Modifiers**: These are bonuses provided by magical properties on your equipment. A +1 sword deals +1 damage; a Flaming sword adds +1d6 fire damage, etc.

**Feats and Abilities**: Some feats (such as Weapon Specialization) add directly to your damage, as described in the feat itself. Other feats, such as Power Attack, *can* modify your damage under certain conditions. Examples would be too numerous to list in this answer; check your feats and class features to determine if you have any that apply here.

Answer (score 3):

Weapon damage doesn't change when you level up, except as the things that influence it change.  Have you increased your Strength or Dexterity modifiers over the last three levels?  Have you taken any feats that increase your weapon damage?  Have you improved the magics on your weapons/armor/boots/etc?  These are the things that will change your normal weapon damage as you level up, not the levelling itself (unless you're a monk fighting unarmed).